# how can block sending message in an ios through programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, messageui

through iphone application how to blocking sms using background service running in iphone . want to listen and trigger when Message send through default message in an iphone. need to block message when we are in travel .

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in a non-jailbroken phone. If it is possible in a jailbroken phone, I don't know how to do it.